# How to set the CSS styles of the image to fit bootstrap width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, width

How to set the CSS styles of the images so that it can fit the full width available by bootstrap 6 columns and scale the height accordingly

```
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="the_image.jpg" class="my_image_style">          
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the boostrap `img-responsive` class.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x100" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a sample [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/113747)